# Как изменить таблицу как в примере

Tags: sql, oracle

Есть таблица(1 изображение) Создать новую таблицу в оракл12 как на втором изображении. Нужно добавить дополнительный столбец следующего вида (value2)

Условия для новой таблицы 1) в  одной строке в столбцах value1 и новом, добавленном, не должны дублироваться значения. 2) не должно быть перекрестных дублей. т.е. если есть строка ab\ac не должно быть ac\ab
[image: начальная таблицу] [image: как должно быть]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно пронумеровать строки и затем создать таблицу с помощью запроса ниже

```
with cte as (select row_number () over (order by value1) as id,value1, number1, number2 from table1)
select c1.value1, c2.value1 as value2, c1.number1, c1.number2 from cte c1
join cte c2 on c1.id<c2.id
order by 1
```

Тут [фиддл](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=214450585a3f80256cfd6e0d84cd6091)